# Надо из значений словаря сделать новый словарь где значения являются ключом а ключ значением

Tags: python, словари, dict

У меня есть словарь

```
{12:['text','text2'], 45:['text2','text3']}
```

Надо получить

```
{'text': [12], 'text2': [12,45], 'text3':[45]}
```

У меня есть код. Но он работает очень медленно(Мне нужно код для работы с большим количеством данных Python).

```
new_data = {}
data = some_dict
keys = data.keys()
for list in data.values():
    for word in list:
          for key in keys:
              if word in data[key]:
                  try:
                      new_data[word] += [key]
                  except KeyError:
                      new_data[word] = [key]
```

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать так:

```
data = {12:['text','text2'], 45:['text2','text3']}

res = dict()
for key, values in data.items():
    for value in values:
        res[value] = res.get(value, []) + [key]
```

возможно для больших объёмов данных такой код будет работать быстрее:

```
res = dict()
for key, values in data.items():
    for value in values:
        if value not in res:
            res[value] = [key]
        else:
            res[value].append(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать `defaultdict` из модуля `collections` [ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d1 = {12:['text','text2'], 45:['text2','text3']}
d2 = defaultdict(list)
for key, values in d1.items():
    for value in values:
        d2[value].append(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю создать словарь "в обратную сторону". Например, если имя человека - ключ, а номер телефона - значение, то можно создать обратный словарь, где ключом будет номер телефона, а значением - имя человека.
Например, ваш первоначальный словарь был dct.
Создаем пустой словарь dict2 = {}.

```
for key in sorted(dct):
    dict2[dct[key]] = key
```

Мы перебираем имена, берем dict от имени (это номер телефона) и говорим, что в dict2 с номером телефона сопоставляется имя.

Comment: Вы не тестировали ваш код на данных из вопроса. Он работает не так как нужно автору вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

[dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault):

```
d1 = {12: ['text', 'text2'], 45: ['text2', 'text3']}

d2 = {}
for k, vv in d1.items():
    for v in vv:
        d2.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```